# How to override Maximo server time with local browser time

Tags: maximo

Our Maximo server is in Huston and we have users working from India.

In the Maximo UI one of fields should auto populate with the current system date and time (i.e Browser date in IST) instead of server time.

EX: When click on change status the status date should be browser date in IST.

If the user moved from India to China, the field should check the browser time and updated the field display in the browser in the Maximo UI.

EX: When click on change status the status date should be browser date in CST.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Also please provide some code (i.e the html). We can't help otherwise. Your question is really broad.

Comment: If setting the Timezone in the User's Profile (as I suggest in my Answer) doesn't achieve your end, and you end up really having to interact directly with the browser, I think achieving your end is going to require significant customization to Maximo.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the timezone in the User's Profile?